# How to use gpu on google colab R?

Tags: r, gpu, google-colaboratory

I had piece of code which was slow to execute on my laptop. Then I thought I would give google colab a try. But it took double the time of what it took on my laptop.

I am not sure how to use the gpu?

I have changed the runtime type and selected GPU as hardware type but still no luck.